# adding personnalized field for tests status on HP QC/ ALM

Tags: workflow, customization, alm, hp-quality-center

On my test plan tab, i'm trying to add another option to my tests technical status "ready, design".. so i'm tring to add: "to review" as shown[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa6hv.png)

I've tried to do it by the customization, but I don't find how.

Thank you

Comment: First thing is you need to be a QC/ALM administrator to do that. It is fairly easy if you have the access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a project admin to perform this action.
Basically you need to change the Lookup List that assigned to this entity and add values you need to the list of possible values.
For details please address ALM Help:
[Customizing Project Entities](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/online_help/Content/Admin/cust_project_entities.htm) and [Customizing Project Lists](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/online_help/Content/Admin/cust_proj_lists.htm)